# How to set criteria field to look in comma separated list values while performing saved search in netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

I am searching vendor code on sales order in the list of values which are comma separated, but formula(text) field is not getting accepted by netsuite. I tried with case and any function.
How to set criteria field to look in comma separated list values while performing saved search in netsuite?

This code does not work for mee:

```
case when {item.vendorcode} IN ('CE263AG','51640A') 
then 1 
else 0
end
```

I'm also tried:

```
any ['CE263AG','51640A']
```

Comment: use parenthesis around the criteria  ({item.vendorcode} IN ('CE263AG','51640A'))

Answer (score 1):

You should use a numeric formula to return 1 and 0 and a text formula if you return "1" and "0". I am not sure if there is a more elegant way to pull the results that you want but the following criteria may work:

```
a. Formula (Numeric) is equal to 1 then 
b. Formula = Case when {item.vendorcode}='CE263AG' OR {item.vendorcode}='51640A' then 1 else 0 end
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
Case when {Name} IN (‘Name1’, ‘Name2’, ‘Name3) then VALUE else OTHER VALUE end
```

Comment: This seems to have been copied in from Microsoft Word or similar. Please make sure that smart-quotes do not end up in code and that your syntax is correct when posting here.